# How to show confirmation alert before leaving the page in angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to show a confirmation alert before leaving the page, but it does not work when I use a link with routerlink, or when I return to the previous page

I currently did this and it works when closing the tab, or reloading the page

```
 $(function(){
     window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = 'Do you really want to leave?';
        }
        return 'Do you really want to leave?';
    };
 });
```

I tried this but sometimes it doesn't work

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) yourfunction($event) {
  return $event.returnValue='Your changes will not be saved';
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewGuard } from './path of ViewGuard';

@Injectable()
export class ConfirmDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<ViewGuard> {
  canDeactivate(target: ViewGuard) {
    if (target.hasChanges) {
      return window.confirm('cancel this page?');
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

And in your routing file provide root like:

```
{ 
  path:'rootPath/',
  component: ViewGuard,
  canDeactivate: [ConfirmDeactivateGuard]
}
```

Register accordingly:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    ConfirmDeactivateGuard
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the answer provided in my comment. It sounds like you want a `CanDeactivate` guard. Your current code doesn't not work with `routerLink` because changing routes on the client (e.g. with Angular) is not unloading the window.